# vuelidate: `not` validator not working with `sameAs` if value is computed

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I can't get the `not` validator to work when used with a computed `sameAs` value.
<sub>I'm using the term "computed" here, but I'm not 100% sure if it's the most accurate one to use. I hope in combination with the reproducible code it is clear what I mean. If there is a better term, please let me know.</sub>

this doesn't work

```
not(sameAs(value))
```

✅ `sameAs` works when used without `not` with a computed value

```
sameAs(value)
```

✅ `not` works when used with a static value

```
not(sameAs("staticvalue"))
```

App.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive, computed } from "vue";
import { useVuelidate } from "@vuelidate/core";
import { required, minLength, email, sameAs, not } from "@vuelidate/validators";

const formData = reactive({
    username: "",
    sameAsComputed: "",
    notSameAsComputed: "",
    notSameAsStatic: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
});

const rules = computed(() => ({
    username: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(6),
    },
    sameAsComputed: {
        notSameAs: sameAs(formData.username),
    },
    notSameAsComputed: {
        notSameAs: not(sameAs(formData.username)), // doesn't work
    },
    notSameAsStatic: {
        notSameAs: not(sameAs("asdf")),
    },
    email: {
        required,
        email,
    },
    password: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(8),
    },
}));

const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, formData);
</script>
```

Full repo for reproduction: https://github.com/tobealive/vue3-vuelidate
Link to `not` in vuelidate docs: https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/validators.html#not

I opened an issue on this a few days ago in the vuelidate repo.

But since I'm still thinking of the most common case where I - as a user - miss something, and also the maintainers seem to be pretty busy, I thought it's legitimate to also put it in here.

If it is resolved, I would close it to relieve the maintainers and hopefully others who encounter this problem will have a solution on stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

I think could had a bug on this combination of validations. I had the same problem and tried that solution and worked well for me:

```
notSameAsComputed: {
    notSameAs: not(sameAs(computed(() => formData.username)))
},
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?